# Архивация данных. Кодирование длин серий (RLE)

Tags: c, инспекция-кода

Всем привет!

Реализовал простой алгоритм сжатия данных RLE, решил поделиться.

Необходимо реализовать две функции: упаковки и распаковки последовательности. Последовательность из не повторяющихся чисел никак не кодируется. Последовательность из повторяющихся чисел кодируется отрицательным счетчиком, и значением числа после него. Обе функции должны быть с переменным параметром, т.е. запись идет не в новый массив, а в тот же который функция и принимает. Можно внутри функции использовать промежуточный массив.

Есть последовательность: 2 3 3 3 5 2 4 4 4 4 4 8 6 8

После запаковки она должна выглядеть так: 2 -3 3 5 2 -5 4 8 6 8

После распаковки: 2 3 3 3 5 2 4 4 4 4 4 8 6 8

Вот код:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int pack(int *p, int A[], int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    int cnt = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int smb = *(A+0);
    for(i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (*(A+i) != smb) 
        {
            if (i && cnt < -1) 
                *(p+k++) = cnt;
            *(p+k++) = smb;
            smb = *(A+i);
            cnt = 0;
        }
        cnt--;
    }
    if (i && cnt < -1) 
        *(p+k++) = cnt;
    *(p+k++) = smb;
    //*(p + k++) = 0;

    return k;
}
void unpack(int *p, int A[], int n)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0,num, smb;
    int *q = (int*)malloc(n*2*sizeof(int));
    while(i<n)
    {
        if (*(p + i) < 0)
        {
            smb = *(p + i + 1);
            num = (*(p+i)*-1);
            for (int k = 0; k < num; k++)
            {
                *(q + j++) = smb;

            }
            i += 2;
        }
        else if(*(p + i)>0)
        {
            *(q + j++) = *(p+i);
            i++;
        }
    }
    for (int l = 0; l < n; l++)
    {
        *(A + l) = *(q + l);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int N = 0;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    int *A = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", (A + i));
    }
    int n = pack(A, A, N);
    printf("%c", '\n');
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d " , *(A + i));
    }
    unpack(A, A, N);
    printf("%c", '\n');
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", *(A + i));
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Отладчиком смотрите что у вас не так...

Comment: Где передается длина массива? Почему 0 считается концом, если во входных данных нуля нет? Куда вы пишете результат? Похоже вы затираете данные которые пытаетесь распаковать - писать следует в другой массив

Comment: если в коде проблема, то следует её явно словами указать. Если вы думаете, что в код рабочий (он делает всё что вы хотите) и вы готовы отзыв получить по любому аспекту кода, то добавьте метку [tag:инспекция-кода] (см. [описание метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/info))

Comment: @SergeyZinovev
 Вопрос переоткрыл, но всё равно уточните пожалуйста, что вы хотите услышать о своем коде? На какие аспекты нам смотреть? (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0/info)

Comment: Знаете, меня очень сильно мучает вопрос, как кодировать одиночное отрицательное число. Ведь если последовательность повторяющиеся чисел кодируется отрицательным счетчиком,то как быть если в последовательности одно отрицательное число?  При распаковке как его отличить от служебной информации?